# How can I add an object to a class then altering it without changing the original object? [Beginner]

Tags: python, class, pointers

I'm an inexperienced Python user having issues with object instances and classes. When I'm appending one instance of a 'child' class ("Item") within a 'parent' class ("Shopping Cart"), and then making changes to the Shopping Cart's instance, that is then also changing the original 'child' item, leading to exponential growth and general sad times all round.

I'm pretty sure this is an issue to do with my understanding of variables, but I would greatly appreciate feedback on best practice to avoid this in future.

Here's my code snippet to show the issue:

```
# Defining classes
class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add(self, new_item):
        if new_item.name not in [item.name for item in self.items]:
            self.items.append(new_item) # I think this makes a pointer to the "new_item" itself
        else:
            for item in self.items:
                if item.name == new_item.name:
                    item.quantity += new_item.quantity # This then alters the "new_item" as well
    
    def __repr__(self):
        for item in self.items:
            return f"Shopping cart: {item.name}, Quantity: {item.quantity}"

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Original item: {self.name}, Quantity: {self.quantity}"

# Adding/printing function
def adding_items(shopping_cart, item):
    shopping_cart.add(item)
    print(item)
    print(shopping_cart)

# Defining objects
item_1 = Item(name="First Item", quantity=2)
shopping_cart_1 = ShoppingCart()

# Adding the same item four times, and the original item is changed as well
adding_items(shopping_cart_1, item_1)
# Original item: First Item, Quantity: 2
# Shopping cart: First Item, Quantity: 2
adding_items(shopping_cart_1, item_1)
# Original item: First Item, Quantity: 4
# Shopping cart: First Item, Quantity: 4
adding_items(shopping_cart_1, item_1)
# Original item: First Item, Quantity: 8
# Shopping cart: First Item, Quantity: 8
adding_items(shopping_cart_1, item_1)
# Original item: First Item, Quantity: 16
# Shopping cart: First Item, Quantity: 16
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Rich

Comment: "Python user having issues with object instances, classes and pointers" *python doesn't have pointers*.

Comment: Anyway, what is it you don't understand exactly? You add the same object to a list, of course if you modify that object, then it will be modified. Are you asking how to copy an object? I think you should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - thanks for that - yes I'm asking how to copy an object, in this instance how to copy the item_1 so that, when it's added to the shopping_basket, I can change the shopping basket instance without changing the original.

Comment: So, IMO the best approach is to create your own `.copy` method to do this. You *can* use the `copy` module for canned (albeit inefficient) functions that can handle most cases, i.e. `copy.copy` for shallow copies and `copy.deepcopy` for deep copies

Comment: Ah I think I was looking for copy.deepcopy([ORIGINAL OBJECT])

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga perfect, that's what I've just found. Much appreciated!

Comment: Again, you should probably write your own method, which would just require something like `return Item(self.name, self.quantity)` here. You also probably can just `copy.copy` instead of `copy.deepcopy`...

Answer (score 0):

copy.copy(ORIGINAL_OBJECT)

So for my original issue the solution was to use this:

```
from copy import copy
# ...
self.items.append(copy(new_item))
```

Thanks you @juanpa.arrivillaga